# Combining line chart and bar chart in AChartEngine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, bar-chart, linechart

I have a problem with displaying combined chart in AChartEngine.
There are two types of chart that are combined: line and bar chart.
The first problem is that the starting point of the line does not start at 0 of x-axis.
I want it to start at x=0 and end at the rightmost side.
The second problem is that the labels on the top of each bar are not centered.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        GraphicalView view = createIntent();
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        layout.addView(view);
    }

    public GraphicalView createIntent() {
        String[] titles = new String[] {"Benchmark line"};
        //List<double []> values = new ArrayList<double []>(); //as y1
        //values.add(new double[] {20.0, 10.0, 30.0, 25.0, 40.0});
        double[] y1 = new double[] {20.0, 10.0, 30.0, 25.0, 40.0};
        List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for(int i=0; i<titles.length ; i++) {
            x.add(new double[] {1,2,3,4,5});
        }
        /*****************************************/
        List<double []> lineValues = new ArrayList<double []>(); //as values
        lineValues.add(new double[] {20, 20, 20, 20, 20});

        int[] colors = new int[] {Color.parseColor("#ea2e49")}; //pink


        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(0);
        int length = mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount(); 
        for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++){ 
            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
            seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(5); 
            seriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true); 
        }


        mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        setChartSettings(mRenderer, "Average Customer Waiting Time", "Table Categories", "Minutes", 0, 6, 0, 120, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0); 
        mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "1 SEAT");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "2 SEATS");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "4 SEATS");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "6 SEATS");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "8 SEATS");
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);

        XYSeries ySeries = new XYSeries("Average Customer Waiting Time");
        ySeries.add(1, y1[0]);
        ySeries.add(2, y1[1]);
        ySeries.add(3, y1[2]);
        ySeries.add(4, y1[3]);
        ySeries.add(5, y1[4]);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer yRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        yRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77c4d3")); //light blue

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildBarDataset(titles, x, lineValues);
        dataset.addSeries(0,ySeries);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, yRenderer);
        yRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        yRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20); //text size on each bar

        String[] types = new String[] {BarChart.TYPE , LineChart.TYPE};
        final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer, types); 
        return grfv;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] {PointStyle.CIRCLE}; 
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(17);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(5f); 
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEDED"));
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { //build benchmark line
            XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer(); //change
            r.setColor(colors[i]);
            r.setPointStyle(styles[i]); 
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return mRenderer;
    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer, String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor, int labelsColor) {
        mRenderer.setChartTitle(title);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        mRenderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        mRenderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {10, 65, 10, 15});
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
        //mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double []> xValues, List<double []> yValues) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i],0);
            double[] xV = xValues.get(i);
            double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
            int seriesLength = xV.length;
            for(int k=0 ; k<seriesLength ; k++) {
                series.add(xV[k],yV[k]);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }
        return dataset;     
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

`x.add(new double[] {1,2,3,4,5})` to: `x.add(new double[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7})`

and

`lineValues.add(new double[] {20, 20, 20, 20, 20})` to: `lineValues.add(new double[] {20, 20, 20, 20, 20,20,20,20})`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com. You could elaborate your answer and help the OP know what it doing wrong.